# Issue with GEE remap function

Tags: google-earth-engine, reclassify, dictionary

I am running into a strange error that I cannot seem to fix.

I want to reclassify an image in Google Earth Engine using lists. The values in one list `bins` represent the pixel values in the raster image. The values in the other list `expected_def` are what I want to assign to the reclassified raster image. I am retrieving the lists from a table. Here is my existing code...

```
// STRATIFIED MAP
var BM30x_VP = BM30_VP.multiply(1000)
var BM30xSub_VP = BM30x_VP.add(Municipality)

// GET LISTS FROM TABLE
var bins = Table.aggregate_array('bin')
var expected_def = Table.aggregate_array('expected_density_deforestation')

// CONVERT OBJECTS IN LISTS TO EE NUMBERS
var convertToNumber = function(item){
  var NumberItem = ee.Number(item)
  return NumberItem
}

var binNumbers = bins.map(convertToNumber)
var expected_defNumbers = expected_def.map(convertToNumber)

print(binNumbers, 'Bin Numbers (Keys)')
print(expected_defNumbers, 'Expected Deforestation (Values)')

// REMAP THE IMAGE WITH THE LISTS (THROWS ERROR MESSAGE)
var reclassifiedImage = BM30xSub_VP.remap(binNumbers,expected_defNumbers,0,'Value');
print(reclassifiedImage)
```

[Link to full code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/3dd5c53c9bf67c5c0256b40226284bf5)

For some reason, when I use the `.remap()` function, I receive the following error message... [image]

I already tried to convert the objects in my lists to numbers, so I am not sure what else I am doing wring. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is produced because each element in **binNumbers** list is type string; not an expected number. You can fix it by using following function:

```
var binNumbers = binNumbers.map(function(ele){
  
  return ee.Number.parse(ele);
  
});
```

Another problem in your code is related to no band named 'Values'. This is fixed as follows:

```
var reclassifiedImage = BM30xSub_VP.remap(binNumbers,expected_defNumbers,0,'b1');
```

Complete code can be accessed [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/a08fcdfc0107926d62520017e5465dc4). After running it at GEE code editor, I got following result without any issue:

[image]